# How to pass content of tapped UITableView cell to linked View Controller?

Tags: objective-c

I have a new View Controller linked to a UITableView instance, so tapping on an entry in the table takes me to that view controller.  How do I now pass the title of the tapped entry to the new view controller?

Comment: Pass the value in `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate method, didSelectRowAtIndexPath, please put this code.

```
newVC *vc = [[newVC alloc] init];
vc.title = [ yourTableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
// push the VC on navigation.
```

The "yourTableDataSource" will be an array that you must be using for determining the value for cell. So use accordingly.

Hope that helps.